# Graph API search with special character in $filter

Tags: c#, filter, microsoft-graph-api, odata, special-characters

Below is the code. If I pass search value of search parameter e.g: M'test. It throws error.

What is the right way to use this code to support special character like "'"?

```
var graphClient = await GetGraphClient();
List<QueryOption> queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>();
queryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$filter", string.Format("startswith(displayName,'{0}')", search)));
var collection = await graphClient.Data.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 7):

> [Escaping single quotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#encoding-query-parameters)
>
> For requests that use single quotes, **if any parameter values also
> contain single quotes, those must be double escaped**; otherwise, the
> request will fail due to invalid syntax.

In your example, `M'test` would need to be `M''test`.

You could likely just use `string.Replace` or regex to replace `'` with `''`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It is working.